# My Chrome extension doesn't show the 48x48 icon in extension page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First of all, I apologize if the question has been already answered. But all solutions I checked are being taken care of on my part.

This is my manifest.json

```
{
"name": "extension name",
"short_name": "extension",
"description": "desc",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "images/icon19.png",
        "38": "images/icon38.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
        },
    "default_title": "title", 
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}, 

"manifest_version": 2,
"update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",
"version": "0.3.4"
}
```

The icons are all created using Photoshop CC and each size corresponds.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: @apsillers you mean replace default_icon with icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `default_icon` field specifies the icon for the browser action button only, not the icon for the entire extension.

To specify an icon for the extension as a whole, use the top-level [`icons` manifest field](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/icons.html):

```
{
    "name": "extension name",
    "short_name": "extension",
    "description": "desc",
    "icons": {
        "48": "images/icon48.png"
    },
    ...
```